# What software is available for recording in 1/60 FPS?

Tags: screen-casting

I am recording my computer screen which updates once a minute. I want to record for around 8-12 hours uninterrupted, and I would prefer not to compress the video because the details are very fine and any grainy pixelation would potentially make the video unreadable.

Is there any (preferably free) software I can use which records at 1/60fps and can output a lossless (or very close to that) format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OBS](https://obsproject.com) is what I use to record my screen. It is mainly for streaming to websites like twitch but they put a functionality of recording the stream as its going that records in lossless. Also you don't need to be streaming to record. Better than any program I have ever used, it's free, and you can change the frame rate!
[image: Picture I found on google of the frame rate highlighted]

Note: look up on YouTube how to setup your desktop for capture

Comment: Can you select just a portion of the screen to capture, or does it have to be the whole screen?

Comment: @IDontWorkAtNASA It can record whatever part of the screen you want

Answer (score 2):

[AutoScreenRecorder](http://www.wisdom-soft.com/products/autoscreenrecorder_free.htm) (currently version 3.1) appears to allow you to record as low as 1 frame per minute in the Pro version only (the free version does not allow altering the framerate).

Answer (score 1):

[Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/download.php) also allows you to record at any frame rate you want.
Though the free version has watermarks in its recordings.